# Perl print shows leading spaces for every element

Tags: arrays, perl

I load a file into an array (every line in array element).
I process the array elements and save to a new file.
I want to print out the new file:

```
print ("Array: @myArray");
```

But - it shows them with leading spaces in every line.
Is there a simple way to print out the array without the leading spaces?

Comment: The bigger question is: Do you need to load your entire file into an array? Usually, it is more efficient to process and print each line separately, and only in cases where the lines depend on each other (such as with sorting or counting) do you need to store the lines before printing them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Matt Fenwick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894284/matt-fenwick) is correct. When your array is in double quotes, Perl will put the value of `$"` (which defaults to a space; see [the perlvar manpage](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)) between the elements. You can just put it outside the quotes:

```
print ('Array: ', @myArray);
```

If you want the elements separated by for example a comma, change the [output field separator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Handle-%3eoutput_field_separator%28-EXPR-%29):

```
use English '-no_match_vars';
$OUTPUT_FIELD_SEPARATOR = ',';     # or "\n" etc.
print ('Array: ', @myArray);
```

Comment: I have no idea what you want to express with the last sentence, please clarify.

Comment: I was refering to `use English` to avoid the cryptic variable names.

Comment: @daxim Thanks, but will Perl use the `OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR` (or should that be `OUTPUT_FIELD_SEPARATOR`?) on an array *in* double quotes?

Comment: For an array in double quotes, Perl separates the elements with for contents of `$"` (the list separator). The default value for this variable is a space.

Answer (score 7):

Yes -- use [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html):

```
my $delimiter = '';  # empty string

my $string = join($delimiter, @myArray);

print "Array: $string";
```

Comment: Your join statement is redundant. `print "Array: ", @myArray;` will do the exact same thing without forcing you to create another copy of a potentially memory intensive variable.